# Access a search bar with VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I'm having issues accessing the search bar with a dropdown menu. It looks like the element that I need to get is named "data-value" so that I can enter a sample id in the search bar but cannot access it.

I've been able to access a search bar in a different website before by using the `.getElementbyID` or `.getElementbyClassName`  and using the `.Value="123"` to enter a sample id but cannot make it work with this website. Unfortunately, this is a company website and cannot be accessed publicly.

This is the code that I see when I click on inspect element on the search bar.

````
<div class="select-input items"> 'event symobol here
    <div class="item" data-value="123456_S11">123456_S11</div>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 4px;opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: -10000px;"> 'event symbol here
    ::after
</div>```

I also tried this that I saw from a different post but it doesn't work.
```For Each pElement In pHTML.getElementsByClassName("item").getElementsByTagName("div").getElementsByAttribute("data-level")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css attribute selector but you will need to ensure you are targeting the right element

```
ie.document.querySelector(".item[data-value]").getAttribute("data-value")
```

This assumes the first match for an element with class item and attribute data-value is the correct one. Otherwise, you need a different strategy such as gathering a nodeList of all matches and indexing in e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll(".item[data-value]").item(1).getAttribute("data-value")
```

Or adding in parent class

```
ie.document.querySelector(".select-input [data-value]").getAttribute("data-value")
```

Comment: I think I'm going the wrong way about this. Instead I think I should use the drop down button and select the list that becomes available after the click event. I found a similar website that has the drop button. This is the website https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp.  I'm trying to click on the example drop down to show the links but it won't work. This is the code I tried based on an answer from a similar question ``` Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("dropbtn")
    HTMLInput.FireEvent "onclick"```

Comment: It's okay. Thank you for taking your time to help me again!

Comment: hi,  sorry... at the time I wrote my comment your comment didn't include the above url for some reason (the comment originally ended at _list that becomes available after the click even_  - which is why I wrote what I did) . I will have a look at the above later today :-)